# Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'const signed char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char [X]'

Tags: c++

I have the following code :

```
typedef       signed char         Char;

static const struct MyStruct
{
    const Char* str;
    // Other fields
}
myList[] =
{
    {"none", /* Other fields */},
    {"main", /* Other fields */},
}
```

But I have compilation errors :

> Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'const Char *' (aka 'const signed char *') with an lvalue of type 'const char [X]

*X is string length*

It's OK when I replace `Char` by `char`, but how can I use `signed char` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"none"`, for example is a `const char[5]` type. Under certain circumstances, this can *decay* to a `const char*`.

Irrespective as to whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` on your platform, `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are **always** distinct types.

C++ does not allow direct decay of a `const char[N]` type to anything other than a `const char*` (or a pointer to a `typedef` of `const char*`), so in your case it is required to issue a diagnostic.

In C++ you have so many other alternatives: `std::string` being the obvious choice in your case.

To examine the type of `char` you have, use

```
std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed
```

from `<limits>`.

Comment: Thank for that quick answer. How can I know if char is signed or unsigned ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat: Wacked that on the end.

Answer (score 3):

> but how can I use signed char ?

By using an array of `signed char` instead of a string literal:

```
signed char none[] = {'n','o','n','e','\0'};

...

myList[] =
{
    {none, /* Other fields */},
    ...
}
```

Note that `char` (the type of the character literal) may be unsigned and if the value is not representable by `signed char`, then the resulting value will be implementation defined.