# How to deduce the size of a compile time a const char string with C++ templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, c++17

I am trying to use `clang++` to expand the template code from [this post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/parsing-strings-at-compile-time-part-i/). Here is what I come up with.

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int requires_inRange(unsigned int i, unsigned int len) {
    return i >= len ? throw i : i;
}

class StrWrap
{
    unsigned size_;
    char * const begin_;

public:
    template< unsigned N >
    constexpr StrWrap( const char(&arr)[N] ) : begin_(arr), size_(N - 1) {
        static_assert( N >= 1, "not a string literal");
    }

    constexpr char operator[]( unsigned i ) {
        return requires_inRange(i, size_), begin_[i];
    }

    constexpr operator const char *() {
        return begin_;
    }

    constexpr unsigned size() {
        return size_;
    }
};

constexpr unsigned count( StrWrap str, char c, unsigned i = 0, unsigned ans = 0 )
{
    return i == str.size() ? ans :
               str[i] == c ? count(str, c, i + 1, ans + 1) :
                             count(str, c, i + 1, ans);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    static_assert( count("dude", 'd') == 2, "d != 2" );
    return 0;
}
```

However, the code from the blog post is not compiling:

**`/usr/bin/clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only test_debugger2.cpp > main.exe`**

```
test_debugger2.cpp:12:48: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'char *const' with an lvalue of type 'const char [5]'
    constexpr StrWrap( const char(&arr)[N] ) : begin_(arr), size_(N - 1) {
                                               ^      ~~~
test_debugger2.cpp:38:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'StrWrap::StrWrap<5>' requested here
    static_assert( count("dude", 'd') == 2, "d != 2" );
                         ^
test_debugger2.cpp:38:20: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert( count("dude", 'd') == 2, "d != 2" );
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

I could find this related question [Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'const signed char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char [X]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685575/cannot-initialize-a-member-subobject-of-type-const-signed-char-with-an-lvalu), but I did not get how I could fix it.

By using the flags `-Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only` I am only asking `clang` to expand the templates and print their expansion to stdout: [Compile-time 'String' Manipulation with Variadic Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492742/compile-time-string-manipulation-with-variadic-templates)

I am trying to learn to do string computations, i.e., string splitting, string concatenation, find, replace, cut, etc, at compile time with C++ Templates which are said to be Turing Complete: [C++ templates Turing-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189172/c-templates-turing-complete), then, I am taking examples as that blog post and expanding them with `clang` to see how they work and how I could use them to solve any compile time (possible) computations with templates.

This is my compiler version:

```
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

How could I fix the template expansion from that blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```cpp
char * const begin_;
```

is a `const` pointer to `char` (the pointer is const, not the thing it points to). This

```cpp
const char(&arr)[N]
```

is a reference to an array of `N` elements of type `const char`. The element of the array are const. You cannot have a pointer to non-const point into an array of const elements (at least not without brute force). You need to either make your pointer a `const char*` or make your array an array of non-const elements…

I guess you mean to write

```cpp
const char* begin_;
```

Note: starting with C++17, you can just use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)…

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The guy on the blog had wrote it `char * const begin_;` instead of `char const * begin_;`

Comment: @user well, then the code from the blog was wrong… ;)